xcode failed to build my project :SDK is not supported by the compiler

Failed to build module 'XXX'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 6.0.2 effective-5.10 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

my xcode version is 16.1 and can't build this

The error seems pretty clear to me so what is the question? I mean it looks like you have to choose between upgrading the SDK, downgrading the swift version for the project or not using that SDK at all.

@JoakimDanielson hello, should I reinstall xcode to a lower version to change the swift verion?

It depends, you can change it for your project or target, search for "swift language" in the Build Settings in Xcode but you might need an older version of Xcode for Swift 5.6, https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/
